# Extracting words between delimiters [] in python

Tags: python

From the below string, I want to extract the words between delimiters `[ ]` like `'Service Current','Service','9991','1.22'`:

```
str='mysrv events Generating Event Name [Service Current], Category [Service] Test [9991] Value [1.22]'
```

How can I extract the same in Python?

Answer (score 24):

First, avoid using `str` as a variable name. `str` already has a meaning in Python and by defining it to be something else you will confuse people.

Having said that you can use the following regular expression:

```
>>> import re
>>> print re.findall(r'\[([^]]*)\]', s)
['Service Current', 'Service', '9991', '1.22']
```

This works as follows:

```
\[   match a literal [
(    start a capturing group
[^]] match anything except a closing ]
*    zero or more of the previous
)    close the capturing group
\]   match a literal ]
```

An alternative regular expression is:

```
r'\[(.*?)\]'
```

This works by using a non-greedy match instead of matching anything except `]`.

Comment: + 1 The expression becomes easier if you just make it non-greedy: `\\[(.*?)\\]`. [Link to `re.findall()`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#re.findall), [link to `re`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html)

Comment: These expressions will match the string `'[]'` as well, returning `['']` (the empty string). If square brackets with no characters between them should be ignored, the `*` can be changed to `+` in the first expression. I.e., `r'\[([^]]+)\]'`. (Interestingly, replacing the `*` in the non-greedy expression doesn't seem to work.)

Answer (score 8):

you can use regex

```
import re
s = re.findall('\[(.*?)\]', str)
```

Comment: hey im struggling to understand this i  how would i modify that code to extract word  from this  ('word°',) so between (' and ') is there any useful tutorials you can direct me to

Answer (score 2):

```
re.findall(r'\[([^\]]*)\]', str)
```