# Python regular words cut

Tags: python

I have string: `'./money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'`

I need string: `'27-10-2011 17:07:02'`

How can i do this in python?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Extracting words between delimiters \[\] in python](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2852484/extracting-words-between-delimiters-in-python)

Answer (score 2):

There are many ways to do this, one way is to use [str.partition](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.partition):

```
text='./money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'
before,_,after = text.partition('[')
print(after[:-1])
# 27-10-2011 17:07:02
```

Another is to use [str.split](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
before,after = text.split('[',1)
print(after[:-1])
# 27-10-2011 17:07:02
```

or [str.find](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.find) and [str.rfind](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#str.rfind):

```
ind1 = text.find('[')+1
ind2 = text.rfind(']')
print(text[ind1:ind2])
```

All these methods rely on the desired substring immediately following the first left-bracket `[`.

The first two methods also rely on the desired substring ending at the next-to-last character in `text`. The last method (using `rfind`) searches from the right for the index of the right-bracket, so it is a little more general, and does not depend on quite so many (potential off-by-one) constants.

Answer (score 1):

If your string has always the same structure this is probably the simplest solution:

```
s = r'./money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'
s[s.find("[")+1:s.find("]")]
```

Update:

After seeing some of the other answers this is a slight improvement:

```
s[s.find("[")+1:-1]
```

Exploiting the fact that the closing square bracket is the last character in your string.

Answer (score 1):

If the format is "fixed", you can also use this

```
>>> s = './money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'
>>> s[-20:-1:]
'27-10-2011 17:07:02'
>>>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use regular expression:

```
import re

s = './money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'
print re.search(r'\[(.*?)\]', s).group(1)
```

Comment: @kame As it turns out you don't. I'm just used to using it when it comes to `.*` followed by something.

Answer (score 0):

Try with a regex :

```
import re
re.findall(".*\[(.*)\]", './money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]')

>>> ['27-10-2011 17:07:02']
```

Answer (score 0):

Probably the easiest way(if you know the string will always be in this format

```
>>> s = './money.log_rotated.27.10.2011_17:15:01:[27-10-2011 17:07:02]'
>>> s[s.index('[') + 1:-1]
'27-10-2011 17:07:02'
```